Nodejs eslint error: Could not find config file
I'm trying to settup typescript and eslint to my new nodejs express app, and got Error: Could not find config file.
My package:
{
  //#######
  //#######
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint": "^9.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

My tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", ".eslintrc.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

My eslintrc.js file:
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:node/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js', 'node_modules'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
  },
};

I've try to add some line and remove lines on eslintrc but nothing seem to fix it, typescript server runing fine but can't quite figgure out what wrong.
Can some one help me?

Did you try an eslint.config.js file instead, as documented on the       TypeScript ESLint plugin website?

I have encountered your same issue starting from:

A nestJs project
An eslintrc.js file
A tsconfig.json file
eslint 9.0.0 in my case (your case 9.3.0)

And I have discovered running the command eslint "{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts" --fix that

ESLint couldn't find an eslint.config.(js|mjs|cjs) file.
From ESLint v9.0.0, the default configuration file is now
eslint.config.js. If you are using a .eslintrc* file, please follow
the migration guide to update your configuration file to the new
format:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide

Solution
Following the migration guide I have runned the command npx @eslint/migrate-config .eslintrc.js that:

Install @eslint/migrate-config in case it's not installed
Generated eslint.config.mjs file from your .eslintrc.js (pay attention that the conversion has been done correctly)
Run now eslint "{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts" --fix or restart ESlint on your IDE and should works fine

